# Repeat an if/elseif/else to completion

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I'd like to be able to loop the `if/elseif/else` statement if it falls onto any of the statement that is not `else`.

`$names` is an array with a couple of names that the user will select.

Right now, the code does work but if the condition falls into any of the `elseif`s then the loop will stop. From the user's perspective it's almost like nothing has happened.

```
if($names[0] == $poster) {
    shuffle($names);   
} elseif($names[1] == $entertainer) {
    shuffle($names);         
} elseif($names[2] == $tunar) {
    shuffle($names);        
} elseif($names[3] == $keeper) {
    shuffle($names);        
} elseif($names[4] == $feeder) {
    shuffle($names);    
} elseif($names[5] == $provider) {
    shuffle($names);
} else {
    echo "This week's roles are:";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($this_week_result) ) {
                $poster = $row['poster'];
                $entertainer = $row['entertainer'];
                $tunar = $row['tunar'];
                $keeper = $row['keeper'];
                $feeder = $row['feeder'];
                $provider = $row['provider'];
    }

        echo $names[0] . " is the Poster <br>";
        echo $names[1] . " is the Entertainer <br>";
        echo $names[2] . " is the Tunar <br>";
        echo $names[3] . " is the Keeper <br>";
        echo $names[4] . " is the Feeder <br>";
        echo $names[5] . " is the Provider <br>";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO funroles 
        (poster,entertainer,tunar, keeper, feeder, provider, date)
        VALUES ('$names[0]','$names[1]','$names[2]','$names[3]','$names[4]','$names[5]','$date')";

        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

Comment: Can you make a recursive function with switch statement instead?

Comment: i didn't understand anything, could you elaborate more please

Comment: Why is this tagged `mysql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you want to keep shuffling until none of the names in `$names` is in the same position it previously was. If I understand it correctly, you can do it without the if/elseif/else structure.

Create an array of the current names that matches the key position of `$names` like this:

```
$current = [$poster, $entertainer, $tunar, $keeper, $feeder, $provider];
```

Then use `array_intersect_assoc` to check if any key/value pairs match, and `shuffle` until none of them do (it will return an empty array).

```
while (array_intersect_assoc($current, $names)) {
    shuffle($names);
}
```

Then do the stuff with your database afterward.